# Python print mystery - How to print without a space

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

How to have the same functionality as below in Python 2.7. No future please.

```
print(item, end="")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

Before the wonderful `end=` (and `sep=`) appeared in Python 3, I used to build up lines within strings and the print out the string in one hit:

```
str = "Three integers:"
for iii in range (3):
    str = "%s %d" % (str, iii)
print s
```

Needless to say, I don't code in Python 2 any more :-)